# is the battery line on an OBD2 plug always on?

Tags: obd

I'm looking at building a circuit that's powered by the OBD2 plug on a car. I can't seem to find if there are any specs around what the [`battery voltage`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics#OBD-II_diagnostic_connector) pin does when the key is removed from ignition. It's entirely possible that the answer is "it depends on the car," but I'm looking to see if anyone knows for sure / can point me to some specs.

Comment: on the cars we have, the 12V is always on. When I connect the OBD scanner, it comes on, even without keys in.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it really belongs in the mechanics stack exchange instead.

Comment: @Passerby the answer to this question informs design decisions for an electronic peripheral, and is more likely to be known by people who have worked with this interface directly. The typical mechanic will use a tool to connect to it, knowing nothing of the protocol / specifications.

Comment: You underestimate mechanics. And there is overlap between EE and the mechanic SE, I just feel this question would be better answered on that stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, all variations exist, that is, constant 12Vdc, Ignition 12Vdc (available after ignition), 12Vdc on Half a key turn, switched ground, and no 12Vdc on the OBD at all.